# How do I keep my Django server running even after I close my ssh session?

Tags: django, server-administration

I figured out how to run my Django application via `sudo python /home/david/myproject/manage.py runserver 68.164.125.221:80`. However, after I quit terminal, the server stops running.

I tried to run this process in the background, but the server just shuts down quickly after I execute `sudo python /home/david/myproject/manage.py runserver 68.164.125.221:80 &`.

How do I keep my Django application running even after I quit my ssh session in terminal?

PS - Sorry if this question strikes you as elementary. Such sillyness ensues when a front-end javascript programmer must turn into a server administrator in break-neck speed.

Comment: Just remember runserver is only for development...

Comment: Wait, why is it only for development? I read that too in Django documentation, but what are the drawbacks? I think it would work fine.

Comment: Don't. Use. Runserver. In. Production. Ever. It's single-threaded. It's insecure. It is not optimized. At all. It is solely and purely a *convenience* to allow you test your code in development. It was never designed nor intended to be used for anything beyond that.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Those are important priorities. What, by the way, are the repercussions of the server being single-threaded?

Comment: @DavidFaux, only ever serving one client at a time. Even if you only ever had 1 hit per second exactly though it's just plain slow.

Comment: Oh yikes, I certainly want more than 1 client to be able to visit my site concurrently. Thank you, I did not know that.

Comment: Are there well-known patches for making the server multithreaded though? Such as http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/05/django-run-development-server-in-multi.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Meet [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Connect through ssh, start screen. This open a virtual console emulator on top of the one provided by ssh. Start your server there.

Then press Ctrl-a, then d. This detach the screen session, keeping it running in the background.

To [R]e-attach to it, use screen -r.

If screen is not installed and you can't install it, you can also start an application in the background by adding a & to the command, as you tried. But you should not close the terminal window then ; just disconnect, with the bash command exit, or Ctrl-d.

The advantage of screen is that you can still read the output from the server, in case there is an error or anything.

Screen is a really powerful tool, with many more commands. You can add a new virtual window with Ctrl-a, then c (for Create) ; switch through windows with Ctrl-a, then n (next) or p (previous), ...

But you need it to be installed to use it. Since you seem to have root access, this shouldn't be a problem.

EDIT: [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) is another great solution for the same use-case.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out screen after installing it. I'm getting a weird `!!! no tgetent - no screen` error upon making the installation, but I'll figure it out.

Comment: Your distribution probably has a package pre-configured ready to be installed. Did you use that ? For debian or ubuntu, it'd be apt-get install screen. That way, it will also install required packages.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I fixed the issue by executing `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev` to get some required c libraries. Wow, screen works great! I just ran the server in a detached emulated terminal and closed my ssh connection. The server is still running :D I verified the process with `pstree` too. I might not use the Django runserver per the comments above, but this answer certainly solves my original question and taught me something new. Thank you :D

Answer (score 22):

Use `screen` to create a new virtual window, and run the server there.

```
$ screen
$ python manage.py runserver
```

You will see that Django server has started running.

Now press `Ctrl+A` and then press the `D` key to detach from that screen. It will say:

```
$ [detached from ###.pts-0.hostname]
```

You can now safely logout from your terminal, log back in to your terminal, do other bits of coding in other directories, go for a vacation, do whatever you want.

---

To return to the screen that you have detached from,

```
$ screen -r
```

To kill the django server now, simply press `Ctrl+C` like you would've done normally.

---

To `terminate` this current screen instead of `detaching` from this screen, use `Ctrl+D`. It will say:

```
$ [screen is terminating]
$
```

Comment: How to get back to Screen after closing Putty. it says no screen to resume

Comment: Not sure about putty

Comment: Re login with putty and use `screen -r`

Answer (score 9):

Use nohup. Change your command as follows:

```
nohup sudo python /home/david/myproject/manage.py runserver 68.164.125.221:80 &
```