# How to host Django 1.10 Web Application on WHM via cpanel?

Tags: python, django, cpanel, vps, whm

I want to host my Django 1.10 web application on WHM(VPS). for that i have installed Django and another necessary tools on WHM(VPS) by `ssh` login. and i also have uploaded my Django application code through `cpanel` in `public_html` directory.

When i run `python manage.py runserver <ip_address:8000>` from ssh terminal, i am able to access that application. but when i close the ssh terminal, it terminates all the running process. so could not access application after that.

So, Is there any way that without running `python manage.py` script i can access Django application?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you should really give this a read through. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656147/how-do-i-keep-my-django-server-running-even-after-i-close-my-ssh-session)

Comment: ok. let me check above solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a built-in development server, it's not really meant to be used when deploying to a remote VPS.

There are some great resources to help you along, but what you're likely going to want to do is deploy your app on a stack using gunicorn or uwsgi as an application server and a web server like Nginx or apache 2 as a reverse proxy.

I personally use Nginx and uwsgi.

There are some great resources explaining how to deploy a Django server. Have a look at this one from digital ocean, it was a great help when I needed to set up a production server correctly: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

best of luck with it!

Comment: Actually i have already uploaded my code on VPS which has centos6.9 and now i have to complete that deployment on VPS only. so is there any way to host on WHM only?

Comment: I guess the most basic thing you could do is just execute the command from an SSH terminal like this: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &`
The "&" puts the process into the background and should continue running when you close the terminal. I don't know about using WHM, I'd say you might need to speak to the provider directly since hosting Django usually involves modifying the reverse proxy configs.