# Run django on background for action

Tags: django, bash, github-actions

I'm trying to test my react app with yarn using Github Actions, I need to have Django running for some tests, however Django has the

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 15, 2021 - 03:32:25
Django version 3.2.6, using settings 'controller.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

message which locks bash, any ideas how I can start Django inside the action so that the action continues to run?

This is currently my action

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Installing dependecies
        run:
          ./install.sh
        shell:
          bash
      - name: Testing backend
        run:
          ./backend-test.sh
        shell:
          bash
      - name: Starting backend
        run:
          ./backend.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
        shell:
          bash
      - name: Testing frontend
        run:
          ./frontend-test.sh
        shell:
          bash
```

And backend.sh does this

```
# Backend test script
cd backend/ && \
    sudo service postgresql start && \
    source .venv/bin/activate && \
    python3 manage.py test
```

Comment: you can use linux screen to run django in a separate shell https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656252/11225821

Comment: So it's the frontend test you're having problems with? What's in `backend.sh` and `frontend-test.sh` ?

Answer (score 0):

you should add `&` at the end of your command running *backend.sh* script to run it in the background. The process ID will printed to screen and you can run others scripts/commands

```yaml
- name: Starting backend
  run:
    ./backend.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
  shell:
    bash
```